# using matched patterns in powershell -replace

Tags: powershell

The following prints out 123$replace456, I'd like it to print 123yyy456. How do I do this in powershell?

```
  $path = '123xxx456'
  $search = "(\d*)xxx(\d*)"
  $replace = 'yyy'
  $path -replace $search, '$1$replace$2'
```

Comment: Use double-quotes in your replace to have the variable expand properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a double-quoted string for the replacement pattern in order for `$replace` to expand correctly. Remember to escape the `$` in front of backreferences (ie `` `$1 ``):

```
$path -replace $search, "`$1$replace`$2"
```